# Any suggestion to replace deprecated tinymce.create() api?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins

Recently, I am working on migrating from version 5 to 6
and found that tinymce.create() is deprecated.

Currently, we are using this for customizing existing open-source image plugins, but after losing this API, I have no idea how to replace it.
Do you have any good suggestion to replace it simply?
or Should I start from scratch from image plugin?

Thanks in advance